# Are objects added or replaced in a mutable array automatically persisted?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am building a very simple app to store data on people like name, age, etc. I give the user the option of changing the data such as when a person has a birthday. I can't figure out the best way to store the data.

I have searched for a long time now and I can't find the simple answer that I am looking for. If I change the data in a mutable array will that data be changed permanently? I mean will that write over the existing code and change the data so that it will still exist when the app is closed and reloaded again?

So far I am not able to do that. I have experience in MySql and Sql server so I have a tendency to go that direction if possible, but I would really like to use a mutable array or mutable dictionary if possible. This may be such an elementary question, but I can't find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some misconceptions.

The objects you create are in memory. There's nothing permanent about them. You have to save them somehow or they are gone when you quit the application and come back.

If you want to save an array, you have a number of options.

If the array contains nothing but objects of type NSString, NSData, NSDate, NSNumber, NSArray, or NSDictionary, you can save the array using the system class NSUserDefaults.

NSArray also has a method writeToFile:atomically: that will save an array of data to a file.

If your array contains any objects other than the types I listed above, though, neither of those approaches (NSUserDefaults or writeToFile:atomically) won't work.

The other option is to use an NSKeyedArchiver to convert the contents of your array to data, and then write that data to a file. In order for that approach to work, every single object i your array, and all the objects in those objects, need to support the NSCoding protocol.

As others have pointed out, you could also use Core Data or mySQL to save your data, but that seems like overkill for just saving an array.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Core Data. It is the easiest way to manage this kind of data storage requirement on iOS.

Take a look at my book, it got good reviews and is perfect for what you are trying to do: [http://www.amazon.com/Pro-Core-Data-iOS-Professionals/dp/1430233559](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430233559)

If you want an easy way to get started, there are tons of online tutorials too. For example Ray has written some good stuff:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: I think this is direction I have to go. I could also use SQLite I guess.

Comment: you can use SQLite directly yes. But take my word for it on this one, Core Data will save you countless hours of debugging and boilerplate code. AND it is backed by SQLite by default on iOS. :)

Comment: Core data is the answer then. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Definitely is the answer. Good luck with it. Post on here if you get stuck. Most people use Core Data for their DB storage needs on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

**Mutable** means you can change the data at any time, so no, it's not permanent.

Answer (score 0):

*Yes, it will be permanent in terms of what you are asking.  Although because the array is mutable it means you can always change the data back, the initial data will be overwritten by this new data.*

**Edit:** No, the information will not remain after closing the app.  You will need to programmatically save it.  I would use [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: This is not what the question is about; OP wants to know if the array is somehow saved to disk or otherwise accessible in its changed state on the next launch of the program.

Comment: Would I be able to test this with the IOS simulator. I am not able to get the data to permanently add to the array. When I close out the simulator the data is gone.

Comment: Jacques Cousteau has it right. I need the data to be available at the next launch of the app.

Comment: My bad, edited the response. The link goes to the official Apple tutorial, so it should be helpful.

Comment: That is the answer then. Core Data. Thank you all for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

CoreData is the way data is normally persisted in Cocoa and Cocoa-Touch. It also gives you some nice extras like undo support. But it has a *big* learning curve.

If what you're doing is super-simple, look at `NSUserDefaults`. If you need a little more flexibility, you could always use `NSArray`'s `-writeToFile:atomically:` and `-initWithContentsOfFile:` (there are also versions of both those methods that take URLs instead of file paths).

Anything more complicated than that, and it's probably worth the trouble learning CoreData.